# Conditional has_one relation depending on a boolean value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relational-database

I'm implementing a password login to a site that has only oAuth login. The User has a relation to a Facebook_account model where it stores facebook data.

I want this relationship to be dependent on value in the User model.

ie. `has_one :facebook_account, if: :fb_login?`

Is this possible or am I doing something wrong?

Using rails 4.0.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do

```
has_one :facebook_account
```

You don't have to assign anything to the association, rails are fine with association being nil. In fact, you don't even need this boolean field, as you can simply call `user.facebook_account.present?`

Comment: Ok, so everything will be happy if there is simply no facebook_account present?

Comment: Yep, by default all fields are nullable. Unless of course you define some db constraint or validation to enforce field to be filled.

Comment: So I can make the validations I have for facebook_account conditional and everything's happy. Cheers.